# Python Unhandled exception in thread started by -blank

Tags: python, unhandled-exception

I have a fair amount of code, which was running very nicely when several different files were inputted. I then inputted a file which had about four times more data, and this error was thrown from `traceback.format_exc()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    Exception in thread SockThread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 152, in manage_socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 280, in handle_request
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 297, in _handle_request_noblock
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 262, in handle_error
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Unhandled exception in thread started by
```

I can put my code up, but there's a fair amount and I have no idea where the error could be. A text file that is inputted is read by a python program. It interprets the file as a 2D array of integers, and outputs this 2D array to another python program, which generated this error. I know for a fact that the 2D array that it outputted is the correct format for the error-generating program to read.

The program does not use multithreading, which I see a lot of people have used when they get this problem. It is not writing to a new file either.

The program does have a list however. When the error is thrown, the list has around 2133435 values in it (normally within 100 of this), this list is much longer than it was for when the other text files were inputted (no more than 330400). Is it possible that it has reached some kind of limit?

Comment: From the name of the last file, it appears that it is trying to handle an error that you expect to handle. Are you passing a file name into the error handler that is now showing as invalid? What file descriptor is being processed in line 262 of handle_error and where is it initialized?

Comment: It looks like you are running your program from within IDLE and this is a problem in IDLE and not in your program.  Can you run it from the command line instead?

Comment: @BlackJack thanks! cmd throws a MemoryError, which is unfortunate but not surpising.

Comment: You are talking about 2D _arrays_ but also how many values a _list_ has within the program — so what is it, arrays or lists?  If it is `list` you may try to use Numpy's array types which store the values more compact than the builtin `list` and `int` types.